# Add button to header of React Navigation header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have this compononet of mine ... where i want to draw a logout button and also hide the back arrow . but i am not able to do so . Can anyone tell me where i am doing it wrong? I have followed the original documentation of react navigation as well but no solution.

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      user: this.props.navigation.state.params.user,
     }
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation}) =>  {
    const { params = {} } = navigation ; 
    return {
      headerTitle : "Welcome",
      headerLeft: null,
      headerRight : (
        <TouchableOpacity
         style={{ backgroundColor: '#29434e' , padding: 10}}
         onPress={() => params.onlogout}
       >
         <Text style={{ marginVertical:5, color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)', fontSize: 20,}}> Logout </Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>   
      ) 
    };
  };

  _Logout = () => {
   this.props.Signout();
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ onlogout : this._Logout , isSaving: false})
  }

    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    Signout: () => dispatch(Signout())
  }
}

export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(Welcome)
```

Comment: Restarting the packager and clearing cache might help

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani the error is removed but the button is still not showing

Comment: I guess you've not return anything in render() method so nothing show on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is component is not getting the header options using static navigationOptions thing but when i try the defaultNavigationOptions it is working perfect and the code is as belows :

```
const otherApp = createStackNavigator({
  Welcome : { 
    screen : WelcomeScreen
  }
},
{
  defaultNavigationOptions : ({navigation}) => ({
    title : 'Welcome',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#29434e',
      shadowColor: 'transparent',
      elevation: 0
    },
    headerRight: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD', padding: 5 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.getParam('logout')}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
          }}>
          Logout
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  })
});
```

Hope it will help someone in future. 
My environment is :

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.3",
"react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the `marginVertical:10` on your `Text` style. Remove it and you should see your button.

Here is a working example: https://snack.expo.io/rJOSqqEHS

[image]

Comment: not working still not visible also the back button is visible now ... i have updated the code and question can you please recheck ?

Comment: Could you please try to reproduce on a snack? Hard to guess what's going on. I just showed you a working example. Thank you!

Comment: it is working on expo but not on react-native cli ! Don't know why ? i have checked it

Comment: static navigationOptions is not working. When i used the default navigation option it work correctly !